# Kmap pairing Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to make a Kmap solving program in C and I've figured out how to make the truth table and the Kmap but now I wanna make pairs of 1s the the Kmap which is a 2D array, the pairing should only be done in powers of 2 like,
1 or 11 or 1111 or 11111111 and nothing in between  here's an example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvWxM.jpg

I don't want the whole solution for it, I just need the basic idea to solve this kind of pairing problem. Thanks in advance.

This is what I've tried, I know its trash, I just cannot figure it out. :(

http://pastie.org/p/57xZta1ypZ9QQvCrQjPsds

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to post your [mre] in the question itself, together with telling us about all details that your debugging has told you.

Comment: "I know its trash" What makes you think so?

Comment: Look up the operator `%` and replace all your magic numbers by named constants. Even the 1s, you need to explain to yourself why you add 1. That should get you several steps further.